# Deploy webjobs on specific build mode

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to deploy webjob using web application with specific build mode.

Say for example,

Publishing my web application in `Release` mode. But, webjob project associated with my webapp is built using default `Debug` mode.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
  "WebJobs": [
    {
      "filePath": "../../SampleWebJobProject/SampleWebJobProject.csproj" // I need to set build mode for this project
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there anyway to explicitly mention the build mode for my webjob project?

Answer (score 1):

I test in my site and when I follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) to deploy webjob, the **webjob using `Release` build mode as default**. So if you still deploy with `Debug` mode, just manually change it to `Release`.

[image]

The [`webjobs-list.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-dotnet-deploy-vs#webjobslist) only contain WebJobs projects of webapp.

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer the question! In my case, issue due to invalid node hierarchy in `Web.Release.Config` and thus web config transforms are not applied in published web job.